# Groovy cannot get flowfile

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have incoming connection(s) to ExecuteScript and want to retrieve the contents of a flow file (JSON file below), trying to map fields from JSON input to get expected output. For that I added the JSON on a generateflowfile process and connect it to ExecuteScript process. My Groovy code inside Script Body is generatig this error.

I want to map it like shown in my groovy code like below

```
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
   import groovy.json.JsonOutput
   import java.util.logging.Logger
   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("")
   def flowFile = session.get()
   if (!flowFile) return
   def flowFileContent
   flowFile = session.read(flowFile, { inputStream ->
   flowFileContent = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputStream)
   } as InputStreamCallback)
   def id = flowFileContent?.identifier
   def x1Data = flowFileContent?."values"?."x1"[0]?.data
   def x1CodeData = flowFileContent?."values"?."x1_code"[0]?.data
   def x1NameData = flowFileContent?."values"?."x1_name"[0]?.data
   def look = [
      "id": id ?: "",
      "x1": x1Data,
      "x1_code": x1CodeData,
      "x1_name": x1NameData
      ]
  def outputJson = JsonOutput.toJson(look)
  flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { outputStream ->
  outputStream.write(outputJson.getBytes("UTF-8"))
} as OutputStreamCallback)
  session.transfer(flowFile, success)
```

I don't know why my code groovy is giving the error below

```
ExecuteScript[id=c8a13771-aa4f-1bd2-a1c7-92c788193ca5] ExecuteScript[id=c8a13771-aa4f-1bd2-a1c7-92c788193ca5] 
 failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: 
 javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException; 
 rolling back sessionorg.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:247)
   at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1357)
   at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
   at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
   at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) 
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)  at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264) at org.apache.nifi.script.impl.GroovyScriptRunner.run(GroovyScriptRunner.java:51)
   at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:230)    ... 10 common frames omittedCaused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155)  ... 13 common frames omittedCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Captions of my process NIFI

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

error with executegroovy

```
ExecuteGroovyScript[id=c8a155c4-aa4f-1bd2-0000-0000767d5aee] java.lang.NullPointerExceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.ProcessSessionWrap.write(ProcessSessionWrap.java:814)    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.ProcessSessionWrap.write(ProcessSessionWrap.java:55) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:191) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)    at Scriptffffffff99f3d962.run(Scriptffffffff99f3d962.groovy:25) at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:473)   at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1357)  at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)  at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Let's say that I've tested this part of my code def id = flowFileContent?.identifier
   def x1Data = flowFileContent?."values"?."x1"[0]?.data
   def x1CodeData = flowFileContent?."values"?."x1_code"[0]?.data
   def x1NameData = flowFileContent?."values"?."x1_name"[0]?.data
   def look = [
      "id": id ?: "",
      "x1": x1Data,
      "x1_code": x1CodeData,
      "x1_name": x1NameData
      ] on an online groovy tool and it was working without error.

Comment: 1. use ExecuteGroovyScript instead of ExecuteScript - it should give you accurate line number from your script that throws exception. 2. your script looks good - the only line i can see which could throw NullPointerException - `flowFileContent?."values"?."x1_name"[0]?.data`. try to add `?`: `"x1_name"?[0]`

Comment: give the line number that throws exception  - then it'll be possible to help without guessing )

Comment: Thank you @daggett I Updated my original code and run it inside executegroovyscript please have a look . ^^

Answer (score 2):

the problem in `flowFile = session.read(...)`

session.read declared as void: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/dec043e590f26ba2f3594f4f297dcd2b7e565ab7/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.java#L681

in groovy if you assign void to a variable - variable gets null

so, this line call `flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {...})` throws NPE because flowFile is null

just change `flowFile = session.read(...)` to `session.read(...)`

---

i would suggest to simplify your code a bit

```
import groovy.json.*

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return
ff = session.write(ff, {inputStream, outputStream->
    def flowFileContent = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputStream)
    ...
    def look = [...]
    def outputJson = JsonOutput.toJson(look)
    outputStream.write(outputJson.getBytes("UTF-8"))
} as StreamCallback)
session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
```

and as soon as you are using ExecuteGroovyScript - the code could be even simpler:

```
import groovy.json.*

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return

def flowFileContent = ff.read().withReader("UTF-8"){r->
    new JsonSlurper().parse(r)
}
...
def look = [...]
ff.write("UTF-8"){w-> 
    new JsonBuilder(look).writeTo(w)
}
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: Oh thank youu so much ^^ How can i do then to read the flowfile and then write the trasformed one? @daggett

Comment: I was following this link https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: Without knowing apache nifi details it seems to me you can just omit the `flowile =` part and keep the `session.write(flowFile, {...})` part which will leave the content read from the `flowFile` in the `flowFileContent` variable. That's reading done. For writing I would suspect you can just re-use the `flowFile` instance you already have and push data to it. Again, this is just guessing based on normal api behavior but seems likely.

Comment: @MatiasBjarland Thank you :) but didn't got you could you please write it as response and then i will try ? Thank you

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Thank you @daggett IS it working for you . ? Im gotting this error i 

ExecuteScript[id=c8a13771-aa4f-1bd2-a1c7-92c788193ca5] ExecuteScript[id=c8a13771-aa4f-1bd2-a1c7-92c788193ca5] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:Script2217.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class JsonSlurper @ line 15, column 27.       def flowFileContent = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputStream)

Comment: oh. you need to add imports. updated.